# How do you call another batch file in a batch file with if statements and inputs?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, input, windows-7

Just greeting you all first before asking a question. Anyways, I've got a part of my code for batch file here and I was wondering why, everytime I input "1" or "2" it would say that the syntax is incorrect & then it would exit. I searched for it all night but couldn't find anything. I've replaced the if else statements with different versions but none of them would work xD. I was wondering if you guys could help me and I'd like to thank you in advance in case i'll forget.

**Here's the code.**

```
set /p ch=[]:
if %ch%==1(
    goto login
)
if %ch%==2(
    goto register
)
:login
call lxer.bat
exit
:register
call rxer.bat
exit
```

So the problem would be:

> It won't call the batch files lxer.bat / rxer.bat
>    (These batch files are in correct directories/at the same folder already)
>   It says something about Syntax and then it would directly close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a space before the `(` in an `if` otherwise `cmd` groups the `(` into the string to be compared. The result is `if string == stringcontaining(` and `cmd` says well, if that, then what?

It's also an idea to ensure that the strings exist. If you simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in response to a `set p` then the variable remains unchanged, so if it isn't already set, `cmd` sees `if == string...` and will object.

The usual way is `if "%ch%"=="2" (`

Comment: Damnit, i had just about pressed enter when i saw `1 new answer to this post` and somehow i knew it was you.

Comment: OH GOD how could I miss that?! xD

Comment: Thank you so much! lmfaooooo im laughing at myself right now

Answer (score 0):

I like this way to put a **[dynamic menu](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsMenu.php#Batch.Menu)** from http://www.dostips.com

**Description:**

> This simple menu framework parses itself for batch labels of certain
>   signature and lists them as menu items. The self-parsing feature makes
>   the menu generic. New menu items can be inserted by adding new
>   function blocks without changing the menu infrastructure.

```
@echo off
Title Example of a dynamic Menu
:menuLOOP
Color 0A & Mode con cols=55 lines=10
echo(
echo(     ====================Menu====================
echo(
for /f "tokens=2* delims=_ " %%A in ('"findstr /b /c:":menu_" "%~f0""') do (
echo        %%A  %%B )
echo(
echo(     ============================================
set choice=
echo( & set /p choice=Make a choice or hit ENTER to quit: || GOTO :EOF
echo( & call :menu_[%choice%]
GOTO:menuLOOP
::*************************
:menu_[1] login
cls
echo(
echo login & pause
call lxer.bat
exit /b
::*************************
:menu_[2] register
cls
echo(
echo register & pause
call rxer.bat
exit /b
::*************************
```

You can also take a look at **[this example with a dynamic menu : DJ Batch Music Player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36268530/sound-in-batch?answertab=active#tab-top)**

Comment: woah! I better try this one too. Thanks!