# How to add conditions with commands in Batch file in command prompt?

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, conditional-statements, command-prompt

I am trying to execute a code in which a list of options are posted and when the corresponding number to the operation is pressed the command is executed and afterwards it asks again which command to perform. I have written the following code but it just runs and the program ends. How can I make it continue or put it in a loop

```
@echo off

echo 1 )System information
echo 2 )Ping
echo 3 )IP configuration
echo 4 )Verify Drivers
echo 5 )Driver List 
set /p num= Type the corresponding number to perform an operation: 
if %num%==1 (
systeminfo 
)
if %num%==2 (
ping www.google.com
)
if %num%==3 (
ipconfig /all
)
if %num%==4 (
verifier
)
if %num%==5 (
driverquery
)
pause
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your last line you omit **`:`**  before start `if '%choice%'=='y' goto start`

```
@echo off
:start
Cls
color 1A
echo 1 )System information
echo 2 )Ping
echo 3 )IP configuration
echo 4 )Verify Drivers
echo 5 )Driver List 
echo 6 )Get Serial Number 
set /p num= Type the corresponding number to perform an operation: 
if %num%==1 (
cls
systeminfo 
)
if %num%==2 (
cls
ping www.google.com
)
if %num%==3 (
cls
ipconfig /all
)
if %num%==4 (
cls
verifier
)
if %num%==5 (
cls
driverquery
)
if %num%==6 (
cls
wmic bios get serialnumber
)
set /p choice="Do you want to restart? Press 'y' and enter for Yes: "
if '%choice%'=='y' goto :start
```

But, i like this way to put a **[dynamic menu](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsMenu.php#Batch.Menu)** from http://www.dostips.com

**Description:**

> This simple menu framework parses itself for batch labels of certain
>   signature and lists them as menu items. The self-parsing feature makes
>   the menu generic. New menu items can be inserted by adding new
>   function blocks without changing the menu infrastructure.

```
@echo off
Title Dynamic Menu
:menuLOOP
Color 1A & Mode con cols=55 lines=15
echo(
echo(     ====================Menu====================
echo(
for /f "tokens=2* delims=_ " %%A in ('"findstr /b /c:":menu_" "%~f0""') do (
echo        %%A  %%B )
echo(
echo(     ============================================
set choice=
echo( & set /p choice=Make a choice or hit ENTER to quit: || GOTO :EOF
echo( & call :menu_[%choice%]
GOTO:menuLOOP
::*************************
:menu_[1] System Information 
cls & color B
Mode con cols=120 lines=70
echo(
systeminfo
echo Hit any key to return to the main menu...
pause>nul
Goto:menuLOOP
::*************************
:menu_[2] Ping
cls & color B
Mode con cols=90 lines=15
echo(
ping www.google.com
echo Hit any key to return to the main menu...
pause>nul
Goto:menuLOOP 
::*************************
:menu_[3] IP configuration
cls & color B
Mode con cols=100 lines=60
echo(
ipconfig /all
echo Hit any key to return to the main menu...
pause>nul
Goto:menuLOOP 
::*************************
:menu_[4] Verify Drivers
cls & color B
Mode con cols=90 lines=15
echo(
verifier
echo Hit any key to return to the main menu...
pause>nul
Goto:menuLOOP 
::*************************
:menu_[5] Driver List
cls & color B
Mode con cols=90 lines=90
echo(
driverquery
echo Hit any key to return to the main menu...
pause>nul
Goto:menuLOOP 
::*************************
:menu_[6] Bios serial Number
cls & color B
Mode con cols=50 lines=15
echo(
wmic bios get serialnumber
echo Hit any key to return to the main menu...
pause>nul
Goto:menuLOOP 
::************************
```

You can also take a look at **[this example with a dynamic menu : DJ Batch Music Player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36268530/sound-in-batch?answertab=active#tab-top)**

Answer (score 0):

I tried myself and I managed to get the following, which may be a little simple, what are your thoughts on this one?

```
:start
cls
color 1A
@echo off
echo 1 )System information
echo 2 )Ping
echo 3 )IP configuration
echo 4 )Verify Drivers
echo 5 )Driver List 
echo 6 )Get Serial Number 
set /p num= Type the corresponding number to perform an operation: 
if %num%==1 (
cls
systeminfo 
)
if %num%==2 (
cls
ping www.google.com
)
if %num%==3 (
cls
ipconfig /all
)
if %num%==4 (
cls
verifier
)
if %num%==5 (
cls
driverquery
)
if %num%==6 (
cls
wmic bios get serialnumber
)
set /p choice="Do you want to restart? Press 'y' and enter for Yes: "
if '%choice%'=='y' goto start
```

This is just another way of doing it I guess; I got it through hit and trial method.

Comment: yes, `goto` is the way to go. You might also be interested in the [choice](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command.